# Field at index seems not to work for vertices count

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a simple mesh of 3 vertices: A - B - C. I want to store the Vertex count in each vertex of itself and neighbour one's.

I compare the result of Vertices Count and it is different. As there are two switch nodes with inverted true-false values, it does not matter which path you follow, at least one value (v1_deg or v2_deg) should match v1_deg_ok (the correct value for the given vertex). Connecting the field at index node output to the store named attribute node shows that field at index always return 1, which is wrong.

[image]

In case anyone wants to dig into the problem, [here is the file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_YiTm6YlvvgGfPAssEjtYrZazMhuSaEY/view?usp=sharing)

Any hint about why Field at Index seems not to be working is very welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's a vertex supposed to store as 'Neighbour's Vertex Count' when a vertex has more than one neighbour?  Could you share the problem you're addressing this way?

Comment: Apologies, I explained myself badly. I do "split edges" of a mesh. Per each edge, I want to know Vertex Count of its 2 vertices in the original mesh. Reading your question made me think that I should store the vertices count in each vertex and extract the information _after_ the split edges. But I still think the nodes should work.

Comment: This may not strike you as very helpful... :) but depending on the problem you're trying to solve, the new Mesh Topology nodes in  3.4 may give you a cleaner way through.

Comment: (They solve the 'one-to-many' problem by letting the user sort the 'many' on a chosen criterion)

Comment: Are you telling me that it is not possible with blender 3.3? :(

Comment: No.. it may be possible to extract the 'special case' as we did before..  so you want the vertex-neighbour-counts of each vertex of an edge, stored on the _edges_?

Comment: I have tried to store (named attribute "v1_deg") "Vertices Count" in the vertex and use the same logic of the graph: `if vertice_index_1 == index then field_at_index( vertice_index_2, named_attribute( "v1_def" )  ) else field_at_index( vertice_index_1, named_attribute( "v2_def" ) )`. Guess... no success!!! I am run out of ideas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140091/discussion-between-robin-betts-and-ditiem).

Comment: Summarising chat discussion: I need the number of neighbours of each vertex in a split edge node before they were split